В чем может быть ошибка обучения детекторной модели?
Используя рекомендации ”TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API“, я обучил детекторную нейронную сеть ("efficientdet-d0”) распознавать изображения коров.
Детекторная модель работает хорошо и распознает всех коров на изображении, даже если их много и ориентация туловища у разных коров разная, например:

Но по какой-то причине, иногда, когда на картинке только одна корова, та же нейронная сеть не может распознать эту корову, и если снизить порог вероятности обнаружения объектов достаточно низко (например на уровне 30%), обученная модель начнет “распознавать” как корову - пустое пространство, в то время как корову, которая есть на картинке, нейронная сеть не может обнаружить, например:

В чем может быть причиная такого странного поведения обученной детекторной модели?
